# Xcode command failed with exit code 1 AND error reading xcodeproj file

Tags: xcode, command, project

The app is being built on another persons computer and then sent to me to test.  I am extremely new to this but have been testing apps for a few months.  I just don't do programming at all.  I can maneuver my way around inside Xcode 7.1 pretty well.  However, I do need to fix these errors in order to test this current app.  Can someone help me out?

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I also have another error that reads

Error reading '/Users/logjam3/Desktop/Cosmo Client/Cosmo Client.xcodeproj'

This is exactly the path to where my project is so I don't know why I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the prefix header source location. You can do this by searching for prefix header then changing the location by pressing the 'file' icon on the right sidebar of Xcode.